# Get some test receipt for in-app purchase IPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

We are implementing in-app purchases for iPhones and we need to get some, for example, stub receipt to test our backend for validating it. I checked several sources and as I understood it's not possible and the only way to do that is to have some existing app in iPhone to be able to generate it. Is it correct? Are there any services which can generate it without the device?

Thanks,